# how to change background TableView without make background tableViewCell same like it?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, background, tableview

ok, I have tableView that will show tableViewCell. But I want to make the two to have a different background because if I changed the tableview background the tableviewCell background just changed into the same as tableView. Is there anyway so I could make them into a different background color? thanks in advance.

It's as if the tableViewCell's background doesn't matter as if it's always clear. The color of the tableViewCell always match the tableView.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for indexPath.row in cellForRowAtIndexPath and change the backgroud color for only two rows -

```
if(indexPath.row < 2)
{
    ///change backgroud here...
}
```

the above will work if you are not using reusable cells.

Comment: but I am using a reusable Cells.. :p

Comment: are you using group table view or simple table view?

Answer (score 0):

```
[tableView  setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:.85 green:.55 blue:.82 alpha:1]];
```

You can change the red , green,blue value and get awesome colors.